# trying format a link in SSRS placeholder as currency

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I'm trying to format a placeholder currency as a link colored blue and underlined so it shows to the user as a link, all I'm getting is black? and no underlining? when I export the report to excel it shows properly but through internet explorer version 11 its just black like the rest of the text? anybody have any ideas? magic wands?

```
               <TablixCell>
              <CellContents>
                <Textbox Name="Measures_Extended_List_Price">
                  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                  <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                      <TextRuns>
                        <TextRun>
                          <Value>=Fields!Extended_List_Price.Value</Value>
                          <Style>
                            <FontSize>9pt</FontSize>
                            <Format>$#,##0</Format>
                            <Color>Blue</Color>  <--- does not render
                          </Style>
                        </TextRun>
                      </TextRuns>
                      <Style>
                        <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
                      </Style>
                    </Paragraph>
                  </Paragraphs>
                  <rd:DefaultName>Measures_Extended_List_Price</rd:DefaultName>
                  <ActionInfo>
                    <Actions>
                      <Action>
                        <Drillthrough>
                          <ReportName>Sales by Customer By Product Category</ReportName>
                          <Parameters>
                            <Parameter Name="pUserID">
                              <Value>=Parameters!pUserID.Value</Value>
                            </Parameter>
                            <Parameter Name="Month">
                              <Value>=Parameters!Month.Value</Value>
                            </Parameter>
                            <Parameter Name="FilterCustomer">
                              <Value>=Fields!Description.Value</Value>
                            </Parameter>
                            <Parameter Name="FilterTerritory">
                              <Value>=Parameters!FilterTerritory.Value</Value>
                            </Parameter>
                          </Parameters>
                        </Drillthrough>
                      </Action>
                    </Actions>
                  </ActionInfo>
                  <ZIndex>19</ZIndex>
                  <Style>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                  </Style>
                </Textbox>
              </CellContents>
            </TablixCell>
```

Comment: Try changing the font properties of the container...presumably a textbox.

Comment: hmm checked that... the textbox container properties match the placeholder .... blue and underlined and also formatted as html not regular text...

Comment: Have you tested it in other versions of IE?   The steps you are doing work for me, but we use IE 10.

Comment: I used to have IE Tester installed on my computer but I don't think it works for newer versions of IE, how can I do that?

Comment: Just tried it in firefox and same results as IE 11

Comment: Use a clean test box and install IE 10?   I have no idea how you can do it, but I'm sure if you Google there will be others who do.

Comment: I don't care about checking this in previous versions, it doesn't work in IE 11 a new Microsoft product just like the brand new ReportBuilder I configured this in.